# Bar plot not showing up in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter

I am trying to create a bar plot for a Pandas Series and the bar plot is not showing up in Jupyter notebook.

When I run the cell, I only get the following and I do not see the bar plot.

```
<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x7fa555abc080>
```

Please advise.

[image: Attached screenshot for your reference]

Comment: you likely need to add "%matplotlib inline" to your code (stick it before or after the import statements, and without speech marks).

Comment: @sk877 Thank you! It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `%matplotlib` magic function in your notebook, before the plot function, preferably in the beginning.  This will enable the inline backend for usage with the IPython Notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline


<your code here>
```